# nbdev_install_git_hooks wouldn't install on windows from vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I had trouble installing `nbdev_install_git_hooks` on vscode on windows.

when executing command it would open up a dialog window `open with`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to running powershell terminal.  Have switched instead to a regular command prompt; and it worked

[image]